# I Can't feed my EJS file with an external js file or an external css file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a problem while feeding my EJS template with a JS script or a CSS file (link).

With the css file a get a mime error, and with the js file i get a 404 error (file not found).

my server file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const productos = require("./desafioClase4");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.set("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set(`views`, `./views`);
app.set(`view engine`, `ejs`);

const server = app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error(`Error en Servidor:${err}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Servidor escuchando en Puerto: ${server.address().port}`);
    }
});
```

my EJS file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <%- include(`../partials/head`) %>
    <title>My EJS App</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="title">Nombre del Producto:</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title"/>
    <label for="price">Precio:</label>
    <input type="number" id="price" name="price"/>
    <label for="thumbnail">Thumbnail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="thumbnail" name="thumbnail"/>
    <button id="sendForm">Enviar Producto</button>
</form>

<h1>All Products</h1>
<%- include(`../partials/list`, {allProducts: allProducts, async: true}) %>
<script src="../../static/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My folder structure:

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0TxS.png)

Thank you for your time

EDIT: SOLVED. It's app.use, not app.set("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

Comment: Typo. Middleware is added with the `use` method not the `set` method.

Comment: I would also use `src="/static/js/index.js"` instead. Client-side paths are relative to the current URL